# H2 Dababase not executing sql query

Tags: sql, spring-boot, spring-security, h2

I Created a Registration and Login project with Spring boot and H2. I need to add few roles initially ie, for admin and User. I am executing the query `INSERT INTO ROLE VALUES (1, "ADMIN");` and its giving me an error `Column "ADMIN" not found; SQL statement: INSERT INTO USER_ROLE VALUES (1, "ADMIN") [42122-197] 42S22/42122`

This is my first project with a database please guide me on what am I doing wrong.

Here is the Screenshot for more details.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Single quote worked for me `INSERT INTO ROLE VALUES (1, 'ADMIN');`